# SFX hunt for a particular cymbal

Tags: sound-libraries, library-sound-effects

I've got a client who used a cymbal swell with the title graphic of their show for the pilot (mixed elsewhere), and now that the series has come to us they want to re-use it, but don't have the original effect. The 20-odd similar choices I sent them from our library were rejected, so I'm hoping someone here might recognize this particular cymbal, and which library it came from (out of all the thousands of canned cymbals, I know! I've got great faith in the knowledge of this community though).

[soundcloud]saxtonpope/cymbal-example[/soundcloud]

Thanks SSD!

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of cymbal washes I used to find buried in CDs from Killer Tracks, APM, or other music licensing companies. If that's the case, you'd need to license this as a needle-drop or production wide buy-out, which could ultimately be expensive. It could get *very* expensive if you don't find its source, still use it, it turns out it does belong to a music library, don't license it, and one of the libraries' golden eared reps finds it while flipping channels.

Is it impossible to contact the original mixer?

Answer (score 0):

take a regular cymbal swell, roll it off at 2K (which is what it sounds like in the sample you sent me) and pitch it so it's the same pitch and tell the producer you found it. I can't believe they are that attached to a cymbal swell...

It sounds like any of the cymbal swells of the Vienna Symph Library would do... If I had time I'd try to duplicate it.

Comment: Yeah, I spent enough time pitching and EQing the first batch that I was hoping someone here would, by some miracle, recognize it immediately ("Oh, I just used that on [i]my[/i] reality show this afternoon!") and I wouldn't have to spend any more time and brainpower trying to coerce the client.

Thanks for the tip- might check out the Vienna if things get dire.

Comment: @Saxton I understand! Argh it's frustrating, isn't it? Let me know how it goes - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's a crash-cymbal played rapidly with mallets with synthetic fur-coated balls in top. Doesn't really matter which brand used as the recording isn't that great to begin with, which makes your search easier :-)

I don't think this particular sound is from a library at all, the snare in the end as well as the rather poor quality tells me it's probably ripped from an overhead drum-channel from a raw demo someone brought to the original composition.

Comment: The hit at the end is actually a separate effect for the graphic. I'm working under the assumption that the cymbal is a canned effect (likely from a bad mp3) placed by the editor of the pilot episode.

Comment: You sure? Thought the snaredrum at 7s sounded very much like recorded behind the cymbal with the same mic to me! Guess that might be pretty obvious in the video :-)

Hm....trying to analyze what might be the source of this.... I get some pretty strong vibes of the KORG Triton here for the instruments, too clean to be a Yamaha SY-85 or Roland Groovestation. It does have some body not normally expected from a KORG, but that might be a matter of mixing. Might also be a keyboard I don't know. But the crash doesn't fit in with the others. You might be right, it does sound very MP3 96Kbps or below.

Comment: I MIGHT have this kind of sound in my drum-pad kit, gonna check when I get back to the studio! I do have both crash- and ride-cymbals as such, but no padded mallets. What exactly - if they told you, that is - was it they didn't like with the previous ones you showed them?

Comment: lol forget wine tasting, this is more amazing than watching someone take a swig of some wine and saying "Tastes kind of like a 1992 red stored in maple barrels in an underground dry store". This is more amazing: "That snaredrum sounds like a Korg 3856XZ sample from the upgrade patch" :)

Comment: If this was facebook I'd be constantly pressing like on Utopia's comment

Comment: but you can say it was a good comment! scroll over the left side of the comment and select the up arrow that appears!